# How do I close a csv file created with pandas (pd.to_csv)?

Tags: python, pandas

I first create the file (appending mode)

```
db.to_csv(DB, mode='a', header=False, sep='\t')
```

then I try to open it:

```
rdb=pd.read_table(DB,sep="\t",header=True,parse_dates=True)
```

And next, Python crashes,probably because the file is open, is not it?

I have tried:
`db.close()` but does not work

Comment: It would help if you would post a short, complete, stand-alone program that demonstrates your error. From your description, I should think a 10-line program would suffice. See http://SSCCE.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to answer here, but for anyone else having this problem, I found the answer here:

[Closing file after using to_csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370046/closing-file-after-using-to-csv)

You can pass to_csv a file object instead of just a path, and then close it yourself, like this:

```
outfile = open(path+'filename.csv', 'wb')
df.to_csv(outfile)
outfile.close()
```