# for word, tag in enumerate(sentence): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've doing POS tagging on Bengali Language 
but this error shows
when i wrote print(word + tag)  then no data goes to the tagged file.

```
    taggedOutput = doTag(tagger,untagged)

    tagged = pd.read_csv("Tagged_bangla_hmm.csv",'w',encoding="utf-8", header=None, delimiter = r'\s+',skip_blank_lines=False, engine='python')

for sentence in tagged:

    for word, tag in  enumerate(sentence):

        tagged.write( word  + tag  )

        print(tagged)

        print('\n\n')

        print ('Finished Tagging')
```

Comment: You're attempting to concatenate an integer to a string. `tagged.write( word  + tag  )` should be `tagged.write( str(word)  + tag  )`

Comment: i changed the code
tagged.write() to tagged.to_csv(str(word)+tag)
then  this happens

tagged.to_csv( str(word)  + tag  )

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: I don't see a call to `tagged.to_csv()` anywhere in your code. You're going to have to post the full code if you want me to help you.

Comment: By the way it's solved.

Comment: but no word or tag transfer to the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly close the file in order to see your changes.

Comment: i also want to close the file but Dataframe have no attribute named close
tagged.close()
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: You should use native open() function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370046/closing-file-after-using-to-csv?rq=1

Comment: it works. Thank you for your valuable time and valuable reply